# Python syntax with for loop and lists, exporting to text file

Tags: python, for-loop, append

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Joining List has integer values with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590165/joining-list-has-integer-values-with-python)

I'm having a syntax problem with for loops and list in python.  I'm trying to export a list of numbers that's exported to a text file that's space delimited.

Example: what should be in the text file
**0 5 10 15 20**

The code I'm using is below, any ideas how to fix this.

```
f = open("test.txt", "w")
mylist=[]
for i in range(0,20+1, 5):      
    mylist.append(i)
    f.writelines(mylist)

f.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
mylist = range(0,20+1,5)
f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.writelines(' '.join(map(str, mylist)))
f.close()
```

Comment: I get an error 
File line 3, in <module>
    f.writelines(' '.join(mylist))
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, int found

Comment: try the edited version, you have to convert the ints into strings.

Comment: That works great also so many ways to skin a cat. :-)

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use `range()` to generate your list of numbers, then you can use this:

```
mylist = map(str, range(0, 20 + 1, 5))
with open("test.txt", "w") as f:
    f.writelines(' '.join(mylist))
```

`map(str, iterable)` will apply `str()` on all elements in this iterable object.

[`with`](http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement) is used to wrap the execution of a block with methods defined by a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#context-managers)  This allows common `try...except...finally` usage patterns to be encapsulated for convenient reuse. What it does in this case is it will *always* close `f`. It is a good practice to use it instead of manually call `f.close()`.

Comment: @RickT Glad to help :) You can also to read on `with` and `map` in the linked documents, as they are very useful common functions to use.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert your list of integers into a list on strings *map()* to make it joinable.

```
mylist = range(0,20+1,5)
f = open("test.txt", "w")
f.writelines(' '.join(map(str, mylist)))
f.close()
```

see also [Joining List has Integer values with python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590165/joining-list-has-integer-values-with-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
...     f.write(' '.join((str(n) for n in xrange(0, 21, 5))))
```