# Python encoding: list to string having special characters and numbers in the list

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

I need to join something like this:

```
["Círculo", 23]
["Triángulo, 25, 19, "dos"]
```

I have seen this post -> [Joining a list that has Integer values with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590165/joining-list-has-integer-values-with-python)

But solutions like:

```
', '.join(map(str, myList)) or ', '.join(str(x) for x in list_of_ints)
```

does not work for me, because special character 'í' makes it fail:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character ... in
>   position ...: ordinal not in range(128)

So what is the pythonic way to solve it? I do not want to check types...
Thx!

Comment: Are you able to define the list elements as unicode? Like this [u'Círculo', 23] 

It will solve your problem using @Blubber's answer

Comment: I would like to avoid it if possible. EDIT: no, I can't :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking about encodings I found a solution that works for me:

```
 u', '.join([unicode(x.decode('utf-8')) if type(x) == type(str()) else unicode(x) for x in a])
```

The trick is to use `decode('utf-8')` for getting a valid 8-bit representation of the character.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thx @Ander2, I did not want to use type check but it looks like is the only way to do it... thx a lot

Answer (score 0):

If you can specify the strings in your list as unicode, like:

```
[u"Círculo", 23]
[u"Triángulo", 25, 19, u"dos"]
```

then this should work:

```
u', '.join(unicode(x) for x in list_of_ints)
```

Assuming you are running Python 2.

Comment: This is working only if you assume @Ander2 comment. Update the response and I will mark it as accepted :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import encodings

a=encodings.utf_16.decode(a[0])
encodings.utf_16.encode(a[0])
```

Have you tried to do it with the encodings module? Maybe you'll get it to work with this.
But doesnt seem to work with the utf_16 encoding...