# How to append string - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to write a function that takes an array, converts it to a string, then appends it together.

Ex. `[1,2,3,4,5,6]` would return `'123456'`.

Here is the code that I tried already, but it gives me the error "list indices must be integers, not str"

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def add_it_up(a,b):
    return a+b

def to_str(a):
    for i in a:
        a[i] = str(a[i])

    reduce(add_it_up, a)
```

---

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

def to_str(a):

    ''.join(map(str, l))
    return a
```

what is wrong with the above code? it is just returning the original a value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Joining List has integer values with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590165/joining-list-has-integer-values-with-python)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel:

```
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> 
>>> ''.join(map(str, l))
'123456'
```

The problem in your code is that `for` loops in Python are really for-each loops. So when you have something like `for i in a`, `i` takes on all of the *elements* of `a`, not the indices of `a`.

So, your loop actually works fine for one iteration, and you successfully set an element of your list to a string (specifically, the element at index `1`, since that's the first value of `i`). *However*, the next `i` will reference this new string element and will consequently cause an error when you do `a[i]`.

This is an interesting phenomenon, so let's look at this with the simplified list `a = [1,2,3]`, which is a sublist of your `a` and just enough to see where and why the error takes place:

```
+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  |  2  |  3  |
+-----+-----+-----+
   ^
   i (loop starts, i takes on first value of list: 1)

+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | '2' |  3  |
+-----+-----+-----+
   ^
   i (we set element at index i (a[1]) to str(a[1]), which is '2')

+-----+-----+-----+
|  1  | '2' |  3  |
+-----+-----+-----+
         ^ 
         i (next iteration, i takes on second value: '2')

Error occurs with a[i], list indices must be integers.
```

---

**Reference**

- [`str.join()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join)
- [`map()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: I'm new to python, what is map & join?

Comment: @MattWalker I added some references.

Comment: `map` takes some function (in this case the function is `str`) and applies it to each element of some list.  The `.join` method of a string takes a list, and inserts the given string between each element of that list.  For more details, google "python map" and "python join".

Comment: I see what you did @arshajii, however when i try to add it into my function to_str(a), and define a as [1,2,3,4,5...], the function just returns a

Comment: @MattWalker You can `def add_it_up(a,b): return str(a) + str(b)` and then `reduce(add_it_up, a)`, if you want to continue with your approach.

Comment: @MattWalker The code you just posted doesn't work because you're not modifying `a`. You can just `return ''.join(map(str, l))`, though.

Answer (score 1):

You could have done it with [join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) and [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
''.join([str(_) for _ in a])
```

Even better (thanks chepner)

```
''.join(str(_) for _ in a)
```

Comment: `join` doesn't require a list, just an iterable. A bare generator is fine.

Comment: I like this the best, except that it doesn't work as the OP requested -- you forgot the commas. Try: ','.join((str(_) for _ in a))

Answer (score 1):

This one should work:

```
>>> t =[1,2]
>>> s=[3,4]
>>> ''.join(str(a) for a in t + s)
'1234'
>>>
```

The official docs provide a good explanation for
[join](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join).
After reading [the generators explanation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) , you should get a feeling about its power :-)

Answer (score 0):

> it gives me the error "list indices must be integers, not str"

occurs because

```
for i in a:
```

iterates over the **elements** in `a`.  The first time through the loop, `i` takes the value `1` so it does

```
a[1] = str(a[1])
```

which changes `a` to

```
[1,"2",3,4,...]
```

then the next time through the loop `i` gets `a[1]` which is now the string `'2'`, and it tries

```
a["2"] = str(a["2"])
```

which fails because you can't index a Python list with a string.

---

Others have explained how to solve your particular problem, but in general, to iterate over the indices of a list, try

```
for i in xrange(0, len(a)):
  ...
```