# Integer list join using string.format

Tags: python, string, list

As [Joining a list that has Integer values with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590165/joining-list-has-integer-values-with-python), the integer list can be joined by converting `str` and then joining them.

BTW, I want to get `foo bar 10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9` where several data are first(`foo`, `bar`), then the size of list `10` and `elements` follows.

I used `string.format` as

```
x = range(10)
out = '{} {} {} {}'.format('foo', 'bar', len(x), x)
```

`out` will be `foo bar 10 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`

To solve problem I can rewrite the code as

```
out = '{} {} {} '.format('foo', 'bar', len(x)) + ' '.join([str(i) for i in x])
```

It looks inconsistent (mixed `string.format` and `join`). I tried

```
slot = ' {}' * len(x)
out = ('{} {} {}' + slot).format('foo', 'bar', len(x), *x)
```

It still unattractive I think. **Is there a way to join integer list using `string.format` only?**

Comment: 'inconsistent' 'unattractive'. Why?

Comment: @LutzHorn inconsistent and unattractive: I want to solve using **one line** `string.format` only.

Comment: Do you actually want to store that string, or is it for printing purpose only?

Comment: printing purpose only

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you favor attractiveness, want to use only one line and with `format` only, you can do

```
'{} {} {}{}'.format('foo', 'bar', len(x), ' {}' * len(x)).format(*x)
# foo bar 10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Comment: Thank you! Is there as simple as `out = '{} {} {} {}'.format('foo', 'bar', len(x), x)`?

Comment: @mskimm Unfortunately, no :(

Comment: Fancy, I didn't know you could chain format() calls :)

Answer (score 5):

I might be missing the point of your question, but you could simply extend the approach you link to as follows:

```
>>> x = range(10)
>>> out = " ".join(map(str, ["foo", "bar", len(x)] + x))
>>> out
'foo bar 10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9'
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use the print function for this:

```
>>> from __future__ import print_function  #Required for Python 2
>>> print('foo', 'bar', len(x), *x)
foo bar 10 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```