# Python: how to print non string array?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm pretty new to python, and I wonder how I can print objects of my class fracture. The str funcion is set properly, I guess

```
def __str__(self):
    if self._denominator == 1:
        return str(self._numerator)
    else:
        return str(self._numerator)+'/'+str(self._denominator)
```

because of

```
>>>print ('%s + %s = %s' % (f1,f2,f1+f2))
1/3 + -1/4 = 1/12
```

Now I'd like to print it properly as a sorted array, and I hoped to get something like

```
>>>print(', '.join(("Sam", "Peter", "James", "Julian", "Ann")))
Sam, Peter, James, Julian, Ann
```

But this didn't work for my fracture or even for numbers (like `print(' < '.join((1,2,3)))`)

All I got was:

```
for i in range(len(fractures)):
    if i+1 == len(fractures):
        print (fractures[i])
    else:
        print (fractures[i], end=' < ')
```

Is this really the best solution? That's quite messing up the code, compared on how easy this works with strings...

Comment: You might want to try defining `__repr__` on your class as well as or instead of `__str__`.

Comment: Just so you know, Python already has a [Fraction](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html) class, so you don't necessarily need to write your own. (also, "[fracture](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fracture)" is probably not the word you're looking for)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Joining List has integer values with python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590165/joining-list-has-integer-values-with-python)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to print "1 < 2 < 3" all you need to do is change the type from an int to a string as such:

```
print(' < '.join(str(n) for n in (1,2,3)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert the ints to strings first:

```
numbers = (1, 2, 3)
print(' < '.join(str(x) for x in numbers))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert your array using `map`:

```
print(' < '.join(map(str,(1,2,3))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert integers to string.

```
print(' < '.join((str(1),str(2),str(3))))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10865384)

Comment: A code block alone does not provide a good answer. Please add explanations (why it solve the issue, where was the mistake, etc...)

Comment: @DennisKriechel, I think OP was pretty about he knew it **worked** for **string**, but it **didn't work** for int, as you can see an example of his using it himself. The question also stated a possible solution(C style), and I answered **convert integers to string** and block of code.