# ERROR TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found ODD NUMBERS

Tags: python, list, concatenation

I'm trying to get all the odd numbers from 1 to **number**, but I'm having some troubles.
How can I fix it?
Output should be like: 1, 3, 5, 7, ...

```
number = input("Number: ")
if number.isdigit():
number = int(number)
if number > 0:
    oddNumbers = []
    for i in range(number):
        temp = i%2
        if temp != 0:
            oddNumbers.append([str(i)])
    conc = ', '.join(oddNumbers)
    print(conc)
else:
    print("Error")
else:
    print("Error")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python: how to print non string array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34744894/python-how-to-print-non-string-array)

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

`oddNumbers.append(str(i))`

Not this:

`oddNumbers.append([str(i)])`

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear. Let's look at the full message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 10, in <module>
    conc = ', '.join(oddNumbers)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, list found
```

So the first item (0) of the "sequence" (in this case `oddNumbers`) was expected to be a `str`, but Python found a `list` in its place.

Let's look at what the value of `oddNumbers` will be after the for-loop by putting a `print` statement under the for-loop:

```
Number: 5
[['1'], ['3']]
```

So we see that the first value in `oddNumbers` is `['1']`. So it is indeed a `list` and not a `str`.

Why is it a `list`?

In this line you add each number as a `str` inside a `list` to `oddNumbers`:

```
oddNumbers.append([str(i)])
```

If you instead just add the number as a `str`:

```
oddNumbers.append(str(i))
```

`oddNumbers` will be a list of `str`'s by the end of the for-loop and the `join` will succeed:

```
Number: 5
['1', '3']
1, 3
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from the `join` function which is a String object method and taking an iterable type argument, like list, tuple, dict, etc..

To work correctly, the argument should contain only string type. In your case, you have a list of a list. That's what the message error trying to tell.

So remove the bracket in the append method in order to add only string in your OddNumbers list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code instead :

```
number = int(input("Number: "))


def get_odd_number(number):
    result = []
    for i in range(number):
        if i % 2 != 0:
            result.append(str(i))
    return result


print(','.join(get_odd_number(number)))
```