# Counting occurrence of all characters in string but only once if character is repeated

Tags: python, string, generator

**Note: Please make sure this is not duplicate, i am trying to find one liner way.**

I am trying to turn string filled with ascii letters to string filled with occurrence of ascii letters.

For example:
 `string1 = 'abc'`.

To turn this into string filled with occurrence of ascii letters, i would simply use one line command:

`string2 = [string1.count(l) for l in string1]`

And this would output:

`[1, 1, 1]`

---

**But** if i had multiple repeated characters in string1, it would look different.

For example: `string1 = 'aaabbbccc'`

And transforming it:

`string2 = [string1.count(l) for l in string1]`

And output would be:

`[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`

---

So as you see, character occurrences are repeated, and i don't know how can i make a generator that prints single occurrence of single letter only once.

So for example:

Instead of:

`[3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]`

Is there a way to output this with single line generator?

`[3, 3, 3]`

Comment: what is the expected output of `aabaab`, where there are repeating characters not next to each other?

Comment: Use `collections.Counter` or a `dict` . I don't see any generators in your question.

Comment: `Counter('aaabbbccc')` -> `Counter({'b': 3, 'a': 3, 'c': 3})`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `collections.Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter('aaabbbccc')
Counter({'a': 3, 'b': 3, 'c': 3})
```

You can get the counts as a sorted list easily by iterating the counter with `string.ascii_lowercase`:

```
>>> import string
>>> c = Counter('aaabbbccc')
>>> [c[l] for l in string.ascii_lowercase]
[3, 3, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thank you but i am trying to turn it more easily to string type, is there a simple way for that?

Comment: @ShellRox you are trying to turn what to a string type? I didn't got that. Do you want the result as `'333'` in this case?

Comment: @MoinuddinQuadri I am trying to output numbers without array form, sorry i haven't mentioned in question.

Comment: @ShellRox check [Joining a list that has Integer values with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590165/joining-a-list-that-has-integer-values-with-python)

Comment: @Uriel Eli You are true mind reader

Comment: It is not necessary to `c.get(l, 0)` with a counter.  Simply `c[l]` will default to `0`.

Comment: @wim I actually needed those 0's for specific solution, but i shrinked it to nessecary amount: `k = [c.get(l, 0) for l in string.ascii_lowercase]; k[:len('aaabbbccc')]`

Comment: @wim thanks, fixed

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in one line with an `OrderedCounter`.

```
>>> from collections import Counter, OrderedDict
>>> class OrderedCounter(Counter, OrderedDict): 
...     pass
...
>>> OrderedCounter('aaabbbccc').values()
[3, 3, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `set`:

```
>>> [string1.count(l) for l in set(string1)]
[3, 3, 3]
```

Set turns a string into a set of distinct characters: e.g. `aabc` and `abbc` but also `acb` will turn into `{'a', 'b', 'c'}`

This is the output you looked for, but you would not know which 3 goes to which character, so in the end you'd be better off using the `Counter` methods suggested

Comment: Hello, do you know how could this output also be turned into a string easily? without brackets, thanks!