# How to make numbers from a list of permutations?

Tags: python, random, permutation, python-itertools

The program gets 5 random numbers(0-9).I generated permutations into a list. 
An example: numbers: 0,1,2,3,4 `list = [(1,0,2,3,4),(1,0,2,4,3),...]` and I would like to get: `list = [10234,10243,...]`
And have to make an exception for 0, of course numbers can't start with 0.
Only 5 digit numbers are accepted. So from the example can't get 1234, because 0 must be included everywhere except for the first.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools


m = np.random.randint(0,10,5)
m = list(m)
print(m)

x = set(itertools.permutations(m))
print(x)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Join a list of items with different types as string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590165/join-a-list-of-items-with-different-types-as-string-in-python)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can simply add:

```
list(map(int,(''.join(map(str,i)) for i in list(x) if i[0] != 0)))
# [44757, 44577, 47574, 74745, 74475,...
```

Comment: Yep, I think that's the most concise way

Comment: This isn't good because only 5 digit numbers are accepted and this got 4 digit numbers as well.

Comment: Check now @BeginnerGuy012