# String to list then square and back to string

Tags: python, string, list

How can I solve this assignment:

Given string in form "3,9,13,4,42" convert to list and for each element calculate his square. Then join that squares to string and write to console.
Input

```
`string = "3,9,13,4,42"`
```

Output

```
`string = "9,81,169,16,1764"`
```

I tryed this:

```
string = "3,9,13,4,42"
l = [int(i) for i in string.split(',')]
for i in l:
    i = i**2
```

Now I have all squares but how to join them in string?

Comment: `','.join([str(int(i)**2) for i in string.split(',')])`. Incidentally, do not use reserved or builtin names such as `list`, etc...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Join a list of items with different types as string in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3590165/join-a-list-of-items-with-different-types-as-string-in-python)

Comment: @keepAlive For reference: [TypeError: 'list' object is not callable in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31087111/4518341)